# Compiling flex / bison program error

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer

I got the following flex and bison code which I want to compile and run:

unari.lex:

```
%{
    #include "unari.tab.h"
    using namespace std;
%}
%option noyywrap

%%

a        {yylval=1;  return TOK_A;}
\n       return '\n';
\+       return '+';
.        /*ignore all rest*/

%%
```

unari.y:

```
%{
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void yyerror(const char *errorinfo);
    int yylex();
%}

%left TOK_A 
%left '+'

%%
line: exp '\n'       {cout<<$1<<endl; return 0;}
      ;
exp: exp exp     {$$=$1+$2;}
      | exp '+' exp    {$$=$1+$3;}
      | TOK_A         {$$=yylval;}
      ;
%%
void yyerror(const char *errorinfo)  { 
      cout<<"problem"<<endl;
}


int main()  {
    while(yyparse()==0);
    return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
calc: lex.yy.o unari.tab.o
    g++ unari.tab.o lex.yy.o -o calc.exe

unari.tab.o: unari.tab.c
    g++ -c unari.tab.c

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
    g++ -c lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c: unari.lex unari.tab.h
    flex unari.lex

unari.tab.c unari.tab.h: unari.y
    bison -d unari.y

clean:
    rm *.h *.c *.o  *.exe
```

The problem is, I get the following error when compiling on windows:

```
makefile1:: *** multiple target patterns. Stop.
```

Does anyone recognizes the problem? I'm breaking my head over this for more than 3 hours already, tried searching the web and found nothing useful....

Comment: The Flex tag is for the ADobe/Apache UI Framework. The Flex-lexer tag is used for the lexical analyzer.

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact makefile?

Comment: This may be your issue: 'unari.tab.c unari.tab.h: unari.y'. Usually there is only one word left of the ':'

Comment: No, that should be fine…

Comment: What's `makefile1`? Or did you type the error message incorrectly? Normally it would start `makefile:[linenumber]:` where `[linenumber]` is the number of the erroneous line (which would be useful to know). `multiple target patterns` is only produced (as far as I know) if you have a static rule with more than one target pattern. Static rules have two `:`'s, and I don't see any such rule in your makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
unari.tab.c unari.tab.h: unari.y
    bison -d unari.y
```

try

```
unari.tab.h: unari.y
    bison -d unari.y

unari.tab.c: unari.y
    bison unari.y
```

There may be other ways to do it, but I'm pretty sure that will work for you.

---

Odd. I copied your files, and once I got all the spaces/tab issues worked out in the Makefile it seem to work fine.

```
[Charlies-MacBook-Pro:~/junk] crb% make clean
rm *.h *.c *.o  *.exe
[Charlies-MacBook-Pro:~/junk] crb% make
bison -d unari.y
unari.y: conflicts: 2 shift/reduce
flex unari.lex
g++ -c lex.yy.c
g++ -c unari.tab.c
g++ unari.tab.o lex.yy.o -o calc.exe


[Charlies-MacBook-Pro:~/junk] crb% which make
/usr/bin/make
[Charlies-MacBook-Pro:~/junk] crb% make --version
GNU Make 3.81
```

Could be issues with make on windows, and I don't have a windows machine. Maybe try googling 'multiple target patterns. Stop.'

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see here (or even in your editor by default) but make is very strict in regard to having tabs before comments on the following line.

```
foo.c foo.h: foo.lex
<tab>command
```

where <tab> represents the tab character. If you have spaces, then it is likely to fail.

P.S. the number of targets to the left of the colon is valid. It means that the command(s) generate all those targets at once.

http://amake.m2osw.com/amake-rules.html

Comment: Made sure there are tabs in there, and after the : there are only spaces, but it didnt work as well...

Comment: Well, maybe Charlie is correct and you're using a make tool that does not support more than one target at once (before the ':').